# Can I use same ad unit id for different banner sizes in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, admob, ads

Can I use same ad unit id for different banner sizes e.g.. for interstitial, medium rectangle? If I can use, how to control the ad to be loaded from Admob account.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly do you need to do? You can use the same ad unit id for different banner sizes. Control the ad? What do you mean by that?

Comment: I have to control the ads in my app. I want to know whether DFP will allow same adUnit to be used for multiple ad sizes allowing me to choose what ad to show on what screen (interstitial, 300x250 banner)